# How to add active class on multi level sidebar in AdminLTE-2.4.5

Tags: html, css, laravel

How to add active class in AdminLTE-2.4.5 sidebar on click 
I my laravel app i added multilevel sidebar and i want to add active class when i click it but i do not have any idea to do that so how can i do that any body help thanks in advance

sidebar image
http://prntscr.com/n1g3kl

this is my html code

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu" data-widget="tree">
    <li class="treeview">
        <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-share"></i> <span>sidebar Menus</span>
            <span class="pull-right-container">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
            </span>
        </a>

        <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li class="treeview">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-tasks"></i> Operation
                    <span class="pull-right-container">
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                    </span>
                </a>
                <ul class="treeview-menu">
                    <li class="treeview">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>General Dashboard</a></li>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="treeview">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-building"></i> Department
                    <span class="pull-right-container">
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                    </span>
                </a>
                <ul class="treeview-menu">
                    <li class="treeview">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Driver
                            <span class="pull-right-container">
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="treeview-menu">
                            <li><a href="{{ URL::to('drivers') }}"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> All Driver</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Pending Approval</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="treeview">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Bd Partner
                    <span class="pull-right-container">
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                    </span>
                </a>
                <ul class="treeview-menu">
                    <li><a href="{{url('/bd-list')}}"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Bd List</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What i did once was add a helper function that checks if the route matches one you pressed on and returns true. If true it is set to active. however I dont have the code and its been a while so try doing something of that sort

Comment: i added image please see above there are no routes

Comment: If you use jquery have a look at https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: have you tried using `<li><a href="{{ URL::to('drivers') }}" class="{{ Request::is('drivers*') ? 'active' : '' }}"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> All Driver</a></li>` ? @Shahid

Comment: the documentation for retrieving request paths : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#accessing-the-request

Comment: yes use this it just for active when there are route